# Correct usage of the word respectively

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering if this is correct:

> "First, we placed napkins under two spot-plates and labelled
>   Temperature (0, 40, 60, 95 Celsius) across the top, Time (0, 2, 4, 6,
>   8, 10 min) on the side, and Bacteria or Fungal on the bottom,
>   respectively."

What I want to convey is that one spot-plate is labelled bacteria and the other is labelled fungal.

Comment: Consider this example: *There is a large and a small shed located at the north and east corners respectively*. Respectively is used to convey that north corner refers to the large shed and that east corner refers to the small shed. In your sentence, respectively would be appropriate if you had previously described two different spot-plates, what is not the case. You may say "...on the side, one with bacteria and the other with fungi."

Comment: Ye-es. It's right enough, but adding the other lists of numbers confuses matters rather, so I had to read it a couple of times to see what you meant (eg is the Temperature and Time on each of them, or one on one and one on the other?)

Comment: First, we placed napkins under two spot-plates and on each labeled Temperature (0, 40, 60, 95 Celsius) across the top and Time (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 min) on the side; one plate we labelled Bacteria, the other Fungal. "

Comment: @Colin, and are the labels on the napkins or the spot-plates?

Comment: Prepare two splot-plates by labeling them each "Temperature (0, 40, 60 90 Celsius)" across the top and "Time (0,2,4,6,8,10 min)" on the side.  On the bottom, label one "Bacteria" and the other "Fungal".   *But why not either bacterial/fungal or bacteria/fungus*?

Comment: on the napkins.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be grammatically incorrect, but it's definitely awkward wording, and lacking in precision of meaning. I'd reword it to something like:

> "First, we placed napkins under two spot-plates and labelled one Bacteria and the other Fungal. We then labelled Temperature (0, 40, 60, 95 Celsius) across the top and Time (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 min) on the side of each napkin."